# Unpivot without using columns names

Tags: sql, oracle, unpivot

Right now my query is resulting data in below format.

```
dbid       askid         amid
================================
d1           m1            a1
```

I want to change the display as

```
SOURCE_ID    DEST_ID
========================
m1             d1
a1             d1
```

We can't use union all, inner joins, cross joins because in real time it is very big query and interacts with n no.of multiple tables and it already have them many no.of 
I tried using unpivot but every time it is storing column names also in to rows.

Sample Query which is resulting data right now:

```
 select DEST_ID,SOURCE_ID from 
    (select        
    t1.id as dbid,
    t2.mid as askid,
    t3.m2idd as amid from
    table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3 where
    t1.actid = t2.senid
    and t2.denid = t2.mkid
    )
    unpivot INCLUDE NULLS (SOURCE_ME_GUID FOR DEST_ME_GUID IN (amid, askid));
```

Comment: Hi James, its Oracle DB

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION ALL` in combination with a `WITH` clause.

You got confused with your join criteria somehow. I suppose either `mkid` or `denid` resides in `table3`. Otherwise you'd be cross joining `table3`. You shouldn't use this 1980s join syntax anyway; it's been made redundant in 1992 for a reason.

```
with ids as
(
  select t1.id as dbid, t2.mid as askid, t3.m2idd as amid 
 from table1 t1
 join table2 t2 on t2.senid = t1.actid
 join table3 t3 on t3.mkid = t2.denid
)
select askid as source_id, dbid as dest_id from ids
union all
select amid as source_id, dbid as dest_id from ids;
```

Comment: Thanks alot Kettner for prompt reply, we are not allowed to use union all, as it is very huge query in real time and it is used in multiple places.

Comment: So `UNION ALL` queries are slow and `PIVOT` queries are fast? That's the first time I hear this. I have tried both our queries with different tables. The excution plans looked always better for the `UNION ALL`query (i.e. less costs by far). Anyway, with 10,000 and 100,000 records the queries were equally fast. With 1,000,000 records, however, the `UNION ALL` query was way faster than the `PIVOT` query. Maybe you should think over your policies :-)

Answer (score 0):

Solution for the above issue.

```
 select dbid as DEST_ID, SOURCE_ID 
from ( 
 select 'd1' dbid, 
 cast('m1' as varchar2(200)) as askid, 
 cast('a1' as varchar2(200)) as amid 
 from dual 
) unpivot INCLUDE NULLS ( 
 SOURCE_ID FOR DEST_ID IN (amid, askid) 
);
```